# Laravel 10 partially unescaping back JSON strings with \n \r escape sequences inside

Tags: php, laravel, routes, escaping, line-breaks

In my Laravel 10 test project I have an issue with JSON files that are read from storage folder and served as simple text output into the browser.

If there is a string field with \r and/or \n escape sequences, some of them are printed as real line-breaks / new-lines in the browser.

I created a reproducible example with HTML code inside the string, but the same issue is also with normal text, provided that there are \n \r escape sequences.

Please focus on the fact that the JSON files are usually rendered in a browser without breaking the page.

Indeed in my case the rendering is not the problem, instead the issue is that the PHP function echo or the return statement are altering the output, printing real \n \r characters instead of escape sequences.

Let's say that I have a text JSON file with this object as content:

```
{"html":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><\/head><body>\n<p style=\"vertical-align:middle;font-size:2em;\" >\ntest\n<\/p><\/body><\/html>"}
```

The HTMl is from a text editor, so it can contain \n and/or \r escape sequences.

If I put the file in the public folder and ask the browser to retrieve its content by its url I get this output:

```
{"html":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><\/head><body>\n<p style=\"vertical-align:middle;font-size:2em;\" >\ntest\n<\/p><\/body><\/html>"}
```

that is correct.

If I put the file in a suitable folder of the storage and apply this route in the web.php file:

```
Route::get('/demo/{filename}', function ($filename) {
  $filePath =Storage::path("public/demo/".$filename);
             
        \Log::Info('file '.$filePath);
       
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        $json = file_get_contents($filePath); 
        \Log::Info($json);

        return $json; //the same if the echo function is used

    } else {
     return view('welcome'); }
 });
```

and then ask the browser to retrieve the file, I get this output:

```
{"html":"\n<\/head>\n

\ntest\n<\/p><\/body><\/html>"}
```

You can see that it's three lines, a line is interposed, and parts are missing. The last line is also bigger in font size, although it cannot be seen here.

(in the sample code you can use the echo function instead of the return statement with same results)

A different output in the log file:

```
[2024-03-26 12:25:29] production.INFO: {"html":"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><\/head><body>
<p style=\"vertical-align:middle;font-size:2em;\" >
test
<\/p><\/body><\/html>"}
```

As you can see, new-lines are there too. The main difference is that it's not rendered as HTML as it happens in the browser, but the output is the same.

Is the issue my code's fault or a Laravel's bug? Can be solved?

Comment: Your JSON contains HTML. If you just output that to the browser as is, the browser will interpret the HTML parts, which will lead to all sorts of… interesting… formatting. Have you looked at the _raw_ value the browser receives ("View source" function)?

Comment: @deceze The issue is not the rendering in the browser. The issue is that the \n \r escape sequences are printed as real \n \r characters (also in logs). Furthermore this happens also with normal text, provided \n \r are present. I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: The only issue appears to be the log output; everything else appears entirely as expected. But the accuracy of the log output should be fairly unimportant, no? I don't know if some Laravel logger magic interprets the escape sequences on purpose. If that's the question you want to pose, then pose that straight forward with about single line of code and two sentences of explanation…

Comment: @deceze I am satisfied with the answer provided by ceejayoz that I accepted, after checking it out. Now my code works. As you say maybe there is also a bug somewhere in regard to the escape sequences of the output. This community may be the right place to point it out if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the raw unparsed JSON as a regular response, which'll be interpreted as HTML, and any tags within it will be interpreted.

You can manually tell the browser you're returning JSON:

```
return response($json)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

or parse the JSON and return a JSON response:

```
$json = json_decode($json);
return response()->json($json);
```

Comment: The issue is not the rendering in the browser. The issue is that the \n \r escape sequences are printed as real \n \r characters (also in logs). Furthermore this happens also with normal text, provided \n \r are present. I edited my question to clarify. However I will take into account your suggestion.

Comment: @P5music That's normal. Parse the JSON if you want it to be treated as real JSON.